# Python: Look for Files that will constantly change name

Tags: python, regex, logging

So, I'll explain briefly my idea, then, what I've tried and errors that I've got so far.

I want to make a Python script that will:
Search for files in a directory, example: /home/mystuff/logs
If he found it, he will execute a command like print('Errors found'), and then stop.
If not, he will keep it executing on and on.

But other logs will be there, so, my intention is to make Python read logs in /home/mystuff/logs filtering by the current date/time only.. since I want it to be executed every 2 minutes.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import os
from time import sleep

infile = r"/home/mystuff/logs`date +%Y-%m-%d`*"

keep_phrases = ["Error",
              "Lost Connection"]

while True:
    with open(infile) as f:
        f = f.readlines()
        if phrase in f:
            cmd = ['#print something']
            erro = 1
        else:
            sleep(1)
```

I've searched for few regex cases for current date, but nothing related to files that will keep changing names according by the date/time.. do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use shell features like command substitutions in file names. To the OS, and to Python, a file name is just a string. But you can easily create a string which contains the current date and time.

```
from datetime import datetime

infile = r"/home/mystuff/logs%s" % datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

(The raw string doesn't do anything useful, because the string doesn't contain any backslashes. But it's harmless, so I left it in.)

You also can't open a wildcard; but you can expand it to a list of actual file names with `glob.glob()`, and loop over the result.

```py
from glob import glob

for file in glob(infile + '*'):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        # ...
```

If you are using a `while True:` loop you need to calculate today's date inside the loop; otherwise you will be perpetually checking for files from the time when the script was started.

In summary, your changed script could look something like this. I have changed the `infile` variable name here because it isn't actually a file or a file name, and fixed a few other errors in your code.

```py
# Unused imports
# import time
# import os
from datetime import datetime
from glob import glob
from time import sleep

keep_phrases = ["Error",
              "Lost Connection"]

while True:
    pattern = "/home/mystuff/logs%s*" % datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    for file in glob(pattern):
        with open(file) as f:
            for line in f:
                if any(phrase in line for phrase in keep_phrases):
                    cmd = ['#print something']
                    erro = 1
                    break
    sleep(120)
```

Comment: This finds files matching the pattern `/home/mystuff/logs2021-07-15*`; if the pattern isn't correct, obviously, adapt it. In particular, I would perhaps expect a dot or dash or underscore between `logs` and the date; but this is obviously not a universal convention.

Comment: Sir, I cant upvote due my new reputation on Stackoverflow, but.. thank you very much.
It gave me a nice way to go, also, you explained everything detail per detail.
I might finish it adapting to my necessities, but once again, thank you.

Comment: (Guessing the gender of a three-legged green avatar is perhaps something you want to avoid, though.)

Comment: (Fixed a typo in the code; sorry about that.)